# API Extractor complains about exported object

Tags: typescript, tsdoc

When running [API Extractor](https://api-extractor.com/) (`npx api-extractor run`), I'm getting an error relating to this code:

```
export const {
  foo: fooey
} = createProvider();
```

The error is:

> Missing release tag for fooey in /home/me/project/src/index.d.ts

Here is my attempt to mark `fooey`, but the error persists:

```
/**                                                                                                                    
 * @beta                                                                                                               
 */                                                                                                                    
export const {                                                                                                         
  /**                                                                                                                  
   * @beta                                                                                                             
   */                                                                                                                  
  foo: fooey                                                                                                                                                                                                           
} = createProvider();
```

How can I add the correct tsdoc to remove the error?